# JS created buttons with parameters for click event missed call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, parameters

I create some button in my HTML from js, depending on a value received as input.
So, easy, if the input is 5, I draw 5 buttons, with the text from 1 to 5.

These buttons need to call a function passing as input the counter of each buttons (button1 passes 1 to the called function, button2 passes 2,...).

This is the problem: all the buttons, when called,call the function with the same input (in the example, the value is 5 for all).

Why? This is what I wrote:

```
var toAdd = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (var i = 0; i < nErog; i++) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.id = 'e' + i;
    //newDiv.className = 'ansbox';
    newDiv.style.margin = "20px";
    newDiv.style.fontSize = "350%";
    newDiv.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    toAdd.appendChild(newDiv);
}
document.getElementById('erogs').appendChild(toAdd);

for (var i = 0; i < nErog; i++) {
    $("#e" + i).dxButton({
        text: i + 1,
        onClick: function () {
            RetrieveErogs(i+1);
        },
        height: "120px",
        width: "120px"
    });
}
```

where RetrieveErogs is

```
function RetrieveErogs(erogatore) {
    alert(erogatore);
}
```

All buttons call the functions with the same value, so I think I missed something specifying the onClick event, but what?

Comment: what about `text` is that same as well?

Comment: @Arvind the text is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `RetrieveErogs(i+1)` with `RetrieveErogs($(this).text())`

OR, Try using a closure:

```
   (function(x){
      $("#e" + x).dxButton({
        text: (1+x),
        onClick: function () {
            RetrieveErogs(1 + x);
        },
        ...
      });
   })(i);
```